# Table from R-Code in Latex

Tags: r, latex

I just get started with knitR and latex to do some reproducible research.

Now I want to create a table from a data frame with:

```
<<>>=
xtable(TAB)
@
```

My question is: How do I get the table into the latex file? I guess there should be a chunk option to evaluate the output of the R-Code for the latex-document.

Thanks in advance!

---

Sorry, here the formatted code that doesnt work properly:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 

<<include = FALSE>>= 
library("xtable") 
data(attitude) 
@ 

<<result='tex'>>= 
xtable(attitude) 
@ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should only post one answer and remove your answer that doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The Solution is:

```
<<results='asis'>>=
xtable(TAB)
@
```